# Convert Matrix to Grid

Tags: matrix, grid

Is there any way to convert a Matrix field to a Grid field for existing entries without losing any data?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is no easy way,

you must write a custom code to get the data from matrix field and add them to grid field

some PHP and MySql code.

I can do this for you if you want, but we need to contact in privet to get more info about your site.

Regard's.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for your offer. I appreciate it. I think I'll just leave it for now.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [EllisLab Playa & Matrix Importer](https://github.com/EllisLab/PlayaMatrixImporter)